# finding hostname using IP address in shell script linux

Tags: shell

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me with this issue, I need a shell script that is capable of finding IP addresses using the hostname.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Your title says "find hostname using IP" and your question says "finding IP using the hostname". Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

To find an IP address from a URL, you can use `nslookup`. If you want only the IP address itself, you can pipe it to `grep` and use a lookbehind regex to filter for the part after the text "Address: ".

```
nslookup google.com | grep -Po "(?<=^Address: ).*"
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried out so far? Though for starters there are a couple of tools you can use to achieve this. If using linux, `nmblookup -A <hostname.com>` would produce something like this
`Looking up status of <IP address>` 
Let me know exactly what you want to achieve.

```
okello@okello-XPS-13-7390:~$ nmblookup -A google.com
Looking up status of 172.217.170.206
```

Comment: by running the command "Ifconfig" on terminal there will be a set of host names and their IPs. I need a script that captures the hostname by its IP address. and after I get the device name based on the IP. change it to a new on a file which I have.(Both the IP and the hostname) many thanks